# automatically change excel cell value depending on current date

Tags: date, excel, vba

I have a column of values infront of respective date of current month . The column cell are C1:C31 [which have some numbers in them] while infront of it is date column which show respective date from 1st Dec to 31st Dec [Lets say these dates are in Column D1 to D31]

I want to display a cell value from C1 to C31 in another cell  "A40" depending on current date

For example today is 7th december so the cell infront of it [D7] is "C7" which has a value "13589"

Now i want the cell A40 to display this value [13589] as per todays date  , when i open excel sheet tomorow [8th dec] this cell [A40] will update the respective value from C8 tomorow .

How to achieve this  ?

Comment: Show some sample data. Show what values you expect to return. Show what YOU HAVE DONE to return the expected values. Stop saying *I want* in your post.

Comment: Please provide sample data with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need an index/match formula...

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$31,MATCH(TODAY(),$D$1:$D$31,0))
```

Comment: just the thing i was looking for , thanks SO. Also how to display yesterdays or 2 days before's value instead of today using that MATCH funtion MATCH(TODAY()?

Comment: Just use `TODAY()-1` or if you only want to step though Mon-Fri you can use something like `NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(),-1)`